# SignalR + SQLNotifications in .NetCore

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi I have a webApi and I want to notify when a record changes in the DB. I'm trying to use SQLNotification but this code generates error

> sqlcommand does not contain definition for Notification

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            }
```

Is posible to use SQLNotifications in NetCore 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be mistaken but I don't believe it is available currently based on:

Microsoft's [announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/) stating:

> Simplified Scale-Out Model 
>   Unfortunately, when it comes to scaling out applications there is no “one size fits all” model – each application is different and has different requirements that need to be considered when scaling out the application. We have worked to improve, and simplify, the scale-out model and are providing a Redis based scale-out component in this Alpha. Support for other providers is being evaluated for the final release, for example service bus.

As well as this [open issue](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/357) and specifically David Fowler's comment:

> It's just a very very bad way to do real time notifications as that's not what sql was meant for.